# Separate data into two different database tables using MySQL and PHP

Tags: mysql, database

I have a product feed that lists clothing items multiple times, once each for every colour and size that the item is available in.

```
ProductID      Product Name               Colour      Size      Price

1              Men's Board Shorts         Blue        S         4.99
1              Men's Board Shorts         Blue        M         4.99
1              Men's Board Shorts         Blue        L         5.99
1              Men's Board Shorts         Red         S         4.99
1              Men's Board Shorts         Red         M         4.99
1              Men's Board Shorts         Red         L         5.99
```

I have two tables: One for the name & ID and another table for the id, colour, size and price for each product.

In the first table, I only want the name of the product to appear ONCE for each product, irrespective of the number of different sizes and colours. In the second table I want the product's ID code, the size and price to appear for each of the different colours that are available.

So I would end up with the following data:

```
Product Table
1     Men's Board Shorts

Options Table
1     Blue     S         4.99
1     Blue     M         4.99
1     Blue     L         5.99
1     Red      S         4.99
1     Red      M         4.99
1     Red      M         5.99
```

The reason for separating the sizes into individual records instead of have size S,M,L in one field is that sometimes the price for the large item is different to the price for the small and medium sized items.

Any ideas to get me started/pointed in the right direction?

Thanks...

Comment: Yes, I already have the tables and the data is coming from a CSV feed. Its currently put in a table called ProductTemp using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation of the 2 tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE product (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR() NOT NULL
  );
 CREATE TABLE options (
  product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  color VARCHAR(30),
  size VARCHAR(10),
  price DECIMAL(10,2)  
 );
```

Fetching & inserting records in the tables:

```
 $result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from ProductTemp GROUP BY ProductID', $conn));

 $result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * from ProductTemp', $conn));

 foreach( $result1 as $v ) {
  $retval1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO product VALUES('$v['ProductID']','$v['Product Name']')", $conn);
  if(!$retval1) {
  echo 'Could not enter data into table product: ' . mysql_error(); 
  exit;
 }
 }

  foreach( $result2 as $v ) { 
 $retval2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO options VALUES('$v['ProductID']','$v['Color']','$v['Size']' , $v['Price'])", $conn); 

if(!$retval2 ) {
  echo 'Could not enter data into table options: ' . mysql_error(); 
  exit;
 }
 }
```

Comment: No. I don't want to extract the data from the two tables, I want to seperate the incoming data and put it into the two seperate tables.

Comment: @PhilJames Where is the data coming from? What application language? Are you inserting new products from a data entry form?

Comment: The data is coming from a csv feed. I've already got it into the mysql database using php.

Comment: which table is the incoming data stored now?

Comment: Currently stored in a table called ProductTemp

Answer (score 0):

First Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) SELECT `p_name` FROM `source_table`;
```

Second Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `options` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `colour` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    `size` char(1) NOT NULL,
    `price` float unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `options` (`colour`, `size`, `price`) SELECT `p_colour`, `p_size`, `p_price` FROM `source_table`;
```

I just hope I understood your question correctly. :)